# Class definition syntax in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am very new to python.I am working with some python code.I am trying to map the python object oriented concepts to those of C++ which I think is a good way to learn.I can across two types of class definitions.

```
class SourcetoPort(Base):
    """"""
    __tablename__ = 'source_to_port'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    port_no        = Column(Integer)
    src_address    = Column(String)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, src_address,port_no):
        """"""
        self.src_address = src_address    
    self.port_no     = port_no
```

and the second one.

```
class Tutorial (object):
  def __init__ (self, connection):
    print "calling Tutorial __init__"
    self.connection = connection
    connection.addListeners(self)
    self.mac_to_port = {} 
    self.matrix={}
```

I want to know what is the difference between the Base in SourcetoPort and object in Tutorial?

Comment: What do you mean by difference? SourcePort is derived from Base and Tutorial is inherited from object.

Comment: Here's the documentation for [`object`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#object). You might find [this explanation](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-new-style-class) (and the link at the bottom of the paragraph) useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using SQLAlchemy in the first case. You definitely could not miss the difference in declaration (or, rather, execution).

Beside the fact that [Python classes are rather different from classes in static languages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47370/java-dev-learning-python-what-concepts-do-i-need-to-wrap-my-head-around/47529#47529), your `SourcePort` class depends on a metaclass.

A [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) is essentially a function that can alter or dynamically generate class contents. It's somehow reminiscent of C++ templates, but acting at runtime (in Python, everything happens at runtime).

So that strange `Base` class, or some of its parents, has a metaclass bound to it. After the `class SourcePort...` statement is executed, the contents of `SourcePort` class are modified by the metaclass. The metaclass reads the initial attributes that explain table name, columns, etc, and adds to `SourcePort` various methods to access database fields by name as if they were `SourcePort`'s fields, getters that might lazily load column contents (if initially declared so), setters that change the 'dirty' state of a `SourcePort` instance, all the mechanics that binds ORM objects to database sessions, etc.

So yes, there's a serious difference.

A bit of unsolicited advice: to better understand Python classes, stop trying to make analogies to C++ classes. They share a few traits, but have a sea of differences. Just learn about Python classes as if these were a totally alien concept.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.2 new style classes were introduced which should have `object` as a parent.  Without having `object` as a (grand)parent it'll be an old style class.  In Python 3 all classes are "new".

Inheritance from the `object` gives many [nice features](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-new-style-class) including descriptors, properties etc.  Even if you're not going to use them, it's good idea to inherit `object` anyway.